# Using php yield / Generator::send() for a "data output stream"

Tags: php, php-generators

I know that yield can be used to create a data iterator, e.g. to read data from a CSV file.

```
function csv_generator($file) {    
  $handle = fopen($file,"r");
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    yield fgetcsv($file);
  }
  fclose($file);
}
```

But the Generator::send() method suggests that I can do the same for sequential writing, instead of reading.

E.g. I want to use the thing like this:

```
function csv_output_generator($file) {
  $handle = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
  while (null !== $row = yield) {
    fputcsv($handle, $row);
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

$output_generator = csv_output_generator($file);
$output_generator->send($rows[0]);
$output_generator->send($rows[1]);
$output_generator->send($rows[2]);
// Close the output generator.
$output_generator->send(null);
```

The above will work, I think.

But `$output_generator->send(null);` for closing seems wrong, or not ideal. It means that I can never send a literal null. Which is ok for csv writing, but maybe there is a use case for sending null.

Is there any "best practice" for using php generators for sequential writing?

Comment: This isn't only an issue with generators. You do have the `while (!feof($handle))` which you need to check 1 time after you've reached the end of file. It's the same problem.

Comment: Well, we're talking semantics here. You could just as well send `true`, `false`, `null`, etc. It's your call. You make a fair point with `null` tho. I dunno, I guess I'd send something like a string that's verbose, but then again that's why I don't design systems, it's probably a horrid idea.

Comment: @apokryfos but thanks to feof() being a separate function, it does not limit the range of possible return values of fgetcsv(). Of course this is pointless with csv, because if fgetcsv() returns null, we know it is EOF. Input iterators are already designed with separate methods for ->valid() and ->current(), so the ->current() can return null without it meaning EOF. But not for output / writing.

Comment: @Andrew I chose null because yield already happens to return null if nothing was sent. yes i could choose a different magic value for this. but ideally i would not use the send() method to close the stream, but a dedicated ->close() method. (which exists not).

Comment: Btw a ->close() method would also be useful for reading sometimes. E.g. to close a csv file handle before EOF.

Comment: @donquixote I'm just saying, getting an additional "end of iterations" result is common when iterating. I don't see any straight forward way around it.

Comment: You could write a class that implements 'Iterator' like generator does but yeah that'd defeat the whole purpose of generators. Otherwise I see no clean way to do it except maybe passing in a special Instance object of a special class.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is a marvelous idea but if you're talking semantics, this 'feels' great.

Check against a class. Like pass in objects of a particular class to terminate the generator. Like:

```
// should probably use namespacing here.
class GeneratorUtilClose {}

class GeneratorUtil {
    public static function close() {
        return new GeneratorUtilClose;
    }
}

function csv_output_generator($file) {
  $handle = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

  while (!(($row = yield) instanceof GeneratorUtilClose)) {
    fputcsv($handle, $row);
  }

  fclose($handle);
}

$output_generator = csv_output_generator($file);
$output_generator->send($rows[0]);
$output_generator->send(GeneratorUtil::close());
```

Added a little factory in here for extra semantic sugar.

Comment: Yes, this will work, and it will allow sending literal NULL. I am not sure this is really an improvement overall, but it is a valid answer I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal either but works without creating any other class

```
function csv_output_generator($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
  try {
    while ($row = yield) {
      fputcsv($handle, $row);
    }
  } catch (ClosedGeneratorException $e) {
    // closing generator
  }

  fclose($handle);
}

$output_generator = csv_output_generator($file);
$output_generator->send($rows[0]);
$output_generator->send($rows[1]);
$output_generator->send($rows[2]);
// Close the output generator.
$output_generator->throw(new ClosedGeneratorException());
```